# Search in dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary defined as seen here:

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, object>> dict = new Dictionary<..>();
```

And a sample code for adding data:

```
dict.Add (X, new Dictionary<string, object> ());
dict [X].Add ("Car", CarObject);
dict [X].Add ("Seller", SellerObject);
dict [X].Add ("Key3", Z);
```

I want to search in the inner dictionary if it contains an object which then contains the following 
`CarObject.Name = (wildcard)X1(wildcard)` of the key "Car" but I just can't seem to get a grasp of how to get into the inner dictionary and then into the object with LINQ in order to search for the value.

Comment: Do you need to provide handling if the value is not a string? If it isn't, how could it contain "X1"?

Answer (score 1):

This will return all matching `KeyValuePair<string, object>`.

```
var query = dict.SelectMany(d => d.Value)
                .Where(i => i.Key == "Key1"
                    && (
                          i.Value is CarObject
                          ? ((CarObject)i.Value).Name.Contains("X1")
                          : false
                       ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var results = dict[X].Where(x => (x.Value is CarObject) && ((CarObject)x.Value).Name.Contains("X1"));
```

If you want to get just the value and not the dictionary, and print the values, you can do this:

```
int X = 0, Z = 1;
dict[X].Add("Key1", CarObject);
dict[X].Add("Key2", SellerObject);
dict[X].Add("Key3", Z);

var results = dict[X].Where(x => (x.Value is CarObject) && ((CarObject)x.Value).Name.Contains("X1")).Select(x => x.Value);
foreach (var str in results)
   Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: What if `Value` is not a string?

Comment: If value was not a string, how could it contain `"X1"`? I agree though, OP needs to clarify.

Comment: See edit. I'm a bit tired, so I actually didn't state what i wanted.

Comment: See, if i wanted it to output all carobjects which matches the criterion, how does this change things?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
dict[X].Where(x => x.Value is CarObject && ((CarObject)x.Value).Name.Contains("X1"));
```

Or:

```
dict[X].Values.OfType<CarObject>().Any(x => x.Name.Contains("X1"))
```